# how do I conditionally display angular mat-tabs on smaller screen?

Tags: angular, responsive-design, angular-material, tabs

I want to place contents in tabs, but only on smaller screen. Otherwise the contents should just fall back to div blocks ( or to other layout defined in css ).
For smaller screen ( @media only screen and (max-width:600px) ), tab should appear

```
<mat-tab-group >
  <mat-tab label="First"><div> Content 1 </div></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Second"><div> Content 2 </div></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Third"><div> Content 3</div> </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Now for larger screen, it has to fall back to three div blocks

```
<div> Content 1 </div>
<div> Content 2 </div>
<div> Content 3</div>
```

How do I achieve this using a single block of code in angular / angular material tabs ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using the [CDK Layout BreakpointObserver](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview) and breaking your content down into separate components. For example:

```
import { BreakpointObserver, Breakpoints } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  
  isHandset$: Observable<boolean> = this.breakpointObserver.observe(Breakpoints.Handset)
    .pipe(
      map(result => result.matches),
      shareReplay()
    );

  constructor(
    private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
  ) { }

}
```

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(isHandset$ | async) === true; then thenTemplate; else elseTemplate"></ng-container>

<ng-template #thenTemplate>
    <mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab label="First"><div> <app-content-1></app-content-1> </div></mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Second"><div> <app-content-2></app-content-2> </div></mat-tab>
      <mat-tab label="Third"><div <app-content-3></app-content-3> </div> </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #elseTemplate>
    <div>
      <div> <app-content-1></app-content-1> </div>
      <div> <app-content-2></app-content-2> </div>
      <div> <app-content-3></app-content-3> </div> 
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Please note that each piece of content will need to be abstracted out into its own sub-component. Some info that I think could be useful, you can find the exact dimensions of each breakpoint and what it is called at [this link](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview#predefined-breakpoints).

Edit: Flipped `ng-if`

Comment: Thanks! Thats close to what I wanted.